# Updating specific part of value in hash map dynamically

Tags: java, json, string, spring-boot, hashmap

I have a spring boot app with a HTTP post request handler. It accepts a payload that I parse and outputs a JSON. I have handled it that it needs to accept a payload of certain parameters(18).

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.google.gson.Gson;




@Validated
@RestController
public class MockController {


    @Autowired
    MockConfig mockconfig;

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MockController.class);




    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String index() {
        return "hello!";
    }
        String[] parse;
    @PostMapping(value = "/")
    public String payloader(@RequestBody String params ) throws IOException{
        LOGGER.debug("code is hitting");
        parse = params.split("\\|"); 
        String key;
        String value;
        String dyn;
        Map<String, String> predictionFeatureMap = mockconfig.getPredictionFeatureMap();

        if(parse.length!=18) {

            key = "Not_enough_parameters";
            value = predictionFeatureMap.get(key);
            Map<?, ?> resultJsonObj = new Gson().fromJson(value, Map.class);

        }
        else {
            key = params;
            value = predictionFeatureMap.get(key);
        }
        return value;
    }
}
```

My config class is where I get the input and output from a file and put them into a hashmap.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class MockConfig {
    private Map<String, String> predictionFeatureMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public Map<String,String> getPredictionFeatureMap() throws IOException {
        return predictionFeatureMap;
    }

    public MockConfig() throws IOException {
        init();
    }

    private Map<String, String> init() throws IOException {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner (new File("src/test/resources/Payload1.txt"));

        int counter = 1;
        String key = "";
        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
            if(counter % 2 != 0) {
                key = sc.nextLine();
            }else {
                predictionFeatureMap.put(key, sc.nextLine());
            }
            counter++;
        }
        sc.close();
        return predictionFeatureMap;
    }




}
```

This is the key and value in the file that I'm trying to work with specifically.

```
Not_enough_parameters
```

```
{"status": false, "errorMessage": "Payload has incorrect amount of parts: expecting: 18, actual:8", "version": "0.97", "coreName": "Patient_Responsibility"}
```

(The JSON string is the response to too much or too little parameters... the paramter length should be 18.)

Example input:

```
ncs|56-2629193|1972-03-28|20190218|77067|6208|3209440|self|-123|-123|-123|0.0|0.0|0.0|0.0|0.0|0.0|0.0
```

This input would pass because it has 18 parameters...

What I want to do is if a user curls for example 5 parameters

```
ncs|56-2629193|1972-03-28|20190218|77067
```

I want the value(JSON error message) to have the 'actual' field updated like:

```
{"status": false, "errorMessage": "Payload has incorrect amount of parts: expecting: 18, actual:5", "version": "0.97", "coreName": "Patient_Responsibility"}
```

without hardcoding it into the txt file or hashmap...

I have tried getting the index of the string and replacing the '8' character with parse.length() and casting it as a char but it just gives me this output:

```
{"status": false, "errorMessage": "Payload has incorrect amount of parts: expecting:1 actual:", "version": "0.97", "coreName": "Nulogix_Patient_Responsibility"}
```

How do I parse or index the JSON to update this value? Or is there a hashmap method to deal with this?

Comment: i had to read this post 10 times until i vaguely understood what it is you want to do. But i still dont understand somethings. `Map<?, ?> resultJsonObj = new Gson().fromJson(value, Map.class);` you are taking a predefined json key from the map and then using Gson to serialize it into a Map? This is not how you error handle in spring boot.

Comment: my suggestion, drop Gson completly, Spring uses jackson, you throw a runtime exception and catch this in a @ControllerAdvice annotated class. There you buld an error response that you return to the calling client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When working with a framework, you usually handle errors using the frameworks way of handling errors.

To handle errors in spring boot you typically use a controller advice that will assist in handling errors. This is created by annotating a class with `@ControllerAdvice`.

There you can catch thrown exceptions and build responses that will be returned to the calling client.

```
@PostMapping(value = "/")
public String payloader(@RequestBody String params ) throws IOException{
    LOGGER.debug("code is hitting");
    parse = params.split("\\|"); 
    String key;
    String value;
    String dyn;
    Map<String, String> predictionFeatureMap = mockconfig.getPredictionFeatureMap();

    if(parse.length!=18) {

        // Here you throw a custom runtime exception and pass what
        // parameters you want that will help you build your error 
        // message you are passing to your client.

        final String errorMessage = String.format(
            "Payload has incorrect amount of parts: expecting:%d actual:%d",
            predictionFeatureMap.size(), 
            parse.length);

        throw new MyException(errorMessage); 

    }
    else {
        key = params;
        value = predictionFeatureMap.get(key);
    }
    return value;
}
```

Then in a controller advice class

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class Foo extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(MyException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<MyCustomErrorBody> handleControllerException(HttpServletRequest request, MyException ex) {

        // Build your error response here and return it. 
        // Create a class that will represent the json error body 
        // and pass it as body and jackson will deserialize it for 
        // you into json automatically.

        final MyCustomErrorBody body = new MyCustomErrorBody(false, ex.getMessage(), "0.97", "Patient_Responsibility")

        return ResponseEntity.unprocessableEntity().body(myCustomErrorBody).build();
    }
}


public class MyCustomErrorBody {

    private boolean status;
    private String errorMessage;
    private String version;
    private String coreName;

    // constructor and getters setters ommitted

}
```

Links about spring boot error handling:

[Official spring boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-error-handling)

[Baeldung exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring](https://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring)